# How to get the next closest value?

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, closest, arrayobject

I have a function in which I iterate with an array of nested objects, whose goal is to create connections between different boxes. In my function I can make a first filter in which I get the different combination options between the boxes but after this step I need to stay only with the one that returns the next closest value of one of the properties of each object.
For example, when I am in box 1, whose order property is 3 and can be combined with any number of boxes, I only need to keep the one whose order property is the next closest value. Preventing that you can connect with one that has a lower value and that has the highest order value of all .

```
for (const indexBox in boxes) {
      if (boxes.hasOwnProperty(indexBox)) {
        const box = boxes[indexBox];
        const combinations = box.filter(b => b.properties.order !== box.properties.order);
     }
}
```

my data

```
[
  {
    x: 200,
    y: 350,
    properties: {
      order: 1,
      name: "A",
      input: {
        0: { id: 1, boxId: 1, color: "azul" },
        1: { id: 2, boxId: 1, color: "rojo" },
      },
      output: {
        0: { id: 1, boxId: 1, color: "azul" },
        1: { id: 2, boxId: 1, color: "rojo" },
      },
    },
  },
  {
    x: 600,
    y: 550,
    properties: {
      order: 2,
      name: "B",
      input: {
        0: { id: 1, boxId: 2, color: "azul" },
        1: { id: 2, boxId: 2, color: "rojo" },
      },
      output: { 0: { id: 1, boxId: 2, color: "verde" } },
    },
  },
  {
    x: 100,
    y: 450,
    properties: {
      order: 3,
      name: "C",
      input: {
        0: { id: 1, boxId: 3, color: "azul" },
        1: { id: 2, boxId: 3, color: "verde" },
      },
      output: {
        0: { id: 1, boxId: 3, color: "azul" },
        1: { id: 2, boxId: 3, color: "rojo" },
      },
    },
  },
]
```

From this filter I get the array of objects, which method should I use to get the one with the next closest order? or maybe there is a way to get it directly in the first filter?

Thank you for your time in advance.

Comment: `b.properties.order === box.properties.order + 1`?

Comment: please post your sample data

Comment: My suggestion will work only, if the (ordered) values are sequential (`0, 1, 2, ... , n`). If there are gaps, the task is much more complex.

Comment: @Teemu I understand... I need the next one closer, because I also want to be able to select some that won't have the sequential value

Comment: Now when you've added the example of data, I'm wondering how will `filter` work with this data, since there's no arrays in data at all, and `filter` is a method of arrays only.

Comment: @Teemu because I turn it into an array in a previous function, I've already changed it

Comment: The simplest way is probably to sort the array by `.properties.order`, and then just pick the next member of the current index you've at hands, or `undefined`, if the current index is the last index.

Comment: @Teemu I manage to do the sorting. How can I keep only the next object?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/qz0wsxk4/